# Drawing more than two curves in one graph, with curves having different ranges

Tags: r, plot, range, yaxis

Let us consider the following R code:

```
x=seq(1,10,1)
y1=runif(10,0,1)
y2=runif(10,0,1)
y3=runif(10,100,200)
matplot(x,cbind(y1,y2,y3),type="l")
```

Here, the range of `y1` and `y2` are different from that of `y3`. As a result, when I create this `matplot`, the curves of `y1` and `y2` comes out to be straight line at the bottom, whereas there is no issue with the curve corresponding to `y3`.

Is there any way by which we can properly plot curves having ranges, which differ to a great extent, in the same graph ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use a logarithmic scale for the y-axis:

```
matplot(seq(1, 10, 1), cbind(runif(10, 0, 1), runif(10, 0, 1), runif(10, 100, 200)),
        type = "l", log = "y")
```

Result:
[image]

You can achieve a similar result using `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 = data.frame(x = seq(1, 10, 1),
                 y1 = runif(10, 0, 1), 
                 y2 = runif(10, 0, 1), 
                 y3 = runif(10, 100, 200))

df1 %>% 
  gather(y, value, -x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) + geom_line(aes(color = y)) + scale_y_log10()
```

Result:
[image]

If you don't want log axes, another option is facets with free axis scales:

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(y, value, -x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(y ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good examples around of plotting a single plot with two different scales, e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-single-plot-with-two-different-y-axes/ However, those usually require the usage of `par(new=t)`, which would usually require a bit of tweaking, i.e. not always intuitive for data exploration.

I would recommend using `ggplot` and `facet_wrap` to plot the lines out in different frames on the same image:

```
library(ggplot2)
out <- data.frame(x=rep(x,3), y=c(y1, y2, y3), gp=unlist(lapply(c("y1", "y2", "y3"), rep, 10)))
ggplot(out, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~gp, scales="free_y", nrow=3)
```

[image]